# Is there a way of creating as many react components as there are items in a API?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know if there is a way (and which one it is) of being able to render as many Card components as there are items in an API.

THis is the api url
https://6033c4d8843b15001793194e.mockapi.io/api/locations

I want to create a card for each item - not manually cause they might change.
How would I do that? I have googled and saw that I could maybe use mapping, but how do I fetch the number of ids there are and render as many cards as there are?

I have the card components and I am already able to fetch the names, id, etc...

```
function Card() {
    const url = "https://6033c4d8843b15001793194e.mockapi.io/api/locations";
    const [locations, setLocations] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            setLocations(response.data)
        })

    }, [url])

    if(locations) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Acme HQ</h1>
                <p>{locations?.[0].name}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>error</h1>
        </div>
    )

   
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Yes, use map function on the API results in render function and then pass props to the card component

Comment: @HarshitRastogi Thank you for your input my friend. I'm kind of a react noob, is there a way you could help me out on that?

Comment: `result.map((data) => <Card {...data} />)` aka just mapping the rezult, as its an array, and rendering the component by passing its data via props to it in a render.

Comment: @Lith How would I do that, lets say get the number of ids? Could you help me out on that?

Comment: "number of ids" you mean the amount in an array? then `result.length` to get the amount aka number of ids. If you mean to pass a specific ID to a rendered card then `result.map((data) => <Card id={data.id} />)`. You hsould be more specific as what you want. In this case the `result` is the data fetched from an API (https://6033c4d8843b15001793194e.mockapi.io/api/locations), the `map` will go thru each object in an array, the `data` is just object data, `Card` is your card component and `{...data}` will pass ALL object data to the component

Comment: @Lith Yes that explains what I am trying to do. I apologize for not being too specific but I'm kind of still looking at the ways of doing what I am trying to accomplish.
I'll take a look into that and get back to you.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` like this and send API information as props to component `<Card/>` than you style your Card component as u want.

```
 {result.map((info) => (
                <Card
                  create={info.createdAt}
                  name={info.name}
                  user={info.userCount}
                  description={info.description}
                  key={info.id}
                />
              ))}
```

Comment: That's amazing @Syed that should do it. So what I am trying to do is get the amount of locations which atm are 20 and create a respective card for each one. 
So that result, should I put that inside my useEffect? Where I am fetching the data from the API?

I understood the rest, the part where you are passing the props to the card component, which then I would style on the Card.js

Comment: yes, you can use `useEffect`  to wait for the data to be fetched from the API. @TomasMota

Comment: I have added my code now, where would I add that? Thank you very much for your time

Comment: @TomasMota the `useEffect` should be executed to fetch and only fect the data, in this case. This code, or mine in the comments, should be put inside a render, or a `return` if using functional components. Since at start you have 0 data, you should either have an `if` to check that `result` is not empty or do `result?.map(/// code ///)`

Comment: So in this case the result, is the response? F